# Get the validation attribute which is setting ModelState's IsValid to false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validationattribute

Is there any way to know which validation attribute caused `ModelState.IsValid == false`.

**Class A**

```
public class A
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DataFormat(DataType.Date, "Must be a Date (DD/MM/YEAR)")]
    [NoFutureDate(ErrorMessage = "Future date is not allowed")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I post the form which have the above mentioned class strongly typed with it's view, then validation attributes will work accordingly.

What if 1 of the 3 validation attributes return an error, say `[NoFutureDate(ErrorMessage = "Future date is not allowed")]`.

OR

What if 2 of the 3 validation attributes return an error, say `[NoFutureDate(ErrorMessage = "Future date is not allowed")]` and `[DataFormat(DataType.Date, "Must be a Date (DD/MM/YEAR)")]`.

Surely my property failed the validations.

**Question**

Is there a way to know which validation attribute caused the error?
Is it the `[DataFormat]` one or both `[DataFormat]` and `[NoFutureDate]`.

Comment: `[DataFormat]` is not a validation attribute  (your `ErrorMessage` parameter is pointless)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Of the 3 mentioned, 2 are custom validation attributes.

Comment: Do you want to know programmatically or do you just want to check in debugger?

Comment: @jumpingcode purely programmatically. As I have to do something on particular validation attribute failure.

Comment: @barnes As far as I know, programmatically, you'll only be able to retrieve the error message for a given field. You'd then need some sort of switch to determine which error message meant which attribute.

Comment: @jumpingcode That's what I thought of. But then I have to keep the record of the error messages and then search this collection with the error message(s) generated at the runtime.

Comment: @barnes Yup, and that sounds horrible.

Comment: @jumpingcode So there is no other way than the one I already thought of(_which sounds horrible_)

Comment: @barnes If you don't want to add flags to your error messages and then operate on those, you could specify the wanted behaviour within the actual implementation of your data attribute class. You would still have to deal with the data annotations provided by .net by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ModelState.IsValidField("YourField")` and `ModelState["Date"].Errors.Contains()`  to detect which one of them fire error.

```
public ActionResult Test(YourModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValidField("Date"))
    {
        var futureDateError = new ModelError("Future date is not allowed");
        var dataFormatError = new ModelError("Must be a Date (DD/MM/YEAR)");

        bool IsFutureDateError = ModelState["Date"].Errors.Contains(futureDateError);
        bool isFormatError     = ModelState["Date"].Errors.Contains(dataFormatError);
    }
    ...... // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi In the below ways you can get the modelstate fields errors programmatically.

Way 1:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
 {
    var modelErrors = new List<string>();
    foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values) 
     {
      foreach (var modelError in modelState.Errors)
      {
        modelErrors.Add(modelError.ErrorMessage);
      }
     }

  }
```

Way 2:

```
string Errors = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
```

Thanks

Karthik